Conceptual doubt about pullback and local coordinates
I'm studying differential forms in manifolds through the book: Differential Geometry and Topology With a View to Dynamical System, by Keith Burns.
I have a conceptual question and I would like you to answer me, if possible. (I'm studying Analysis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and this part of differential forms I have to follow with a book on differential geometry.)

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $\psi : U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow V \subseteq M$ be  chart. If $\omega$ is a differential form in $M$, then I'm wrong to say that $\omega$ can be written in local coordinates as
$$
\omega = \sum_{j_1 < \dots < j_k} f(x)\,dx_{j_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{j_k} 
$$
is the same thing to calculate $\psi^*\omega?$


Looks a bit like you have it backwards. A chart is a map $\phi:M\to\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$. What you have is a parametrization $\psi=\phi^{-1}$ (judging by your naming and symbols). Nitpicky, but important. You can not „directly“ write this without a bit more knowledge, only in local coordinates. However, you can embed your manifold in $\mathbb{R}^m$ for large enough $m$ and then write the diff-form on it, taking the pullback then amounts to what I think you are asking.
